# What M9 stands for

Tags: molecular-biology, microbiology

Can anyone tell me what **M9** stands for in M9 medium?

I have tried googling but I still cannot find it.

Comment: I wasn't able to find an original source either but I wouldn't be surprised if it was the 9th version of some minimal medium that was used; M could be minimal or medium or a non-English equivalent. That doesn't mean the history isn't interesting for curiosity's sake but it won't tell you anything else. In any case, the modern M9 has multiple recipes that deviate slightly from one another anyways.

Comment: https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/A1374401

Comment: Original usage seems to be Miller J.H. (1972) Experiments in Molecular Genetics.